# Timing problerm on Workbook_Open()

Tags: excel, events, timing, vba

I think I'm running on a timing problem here.

**Scenario:**
have an helper add-in checking for updates upon Excel starts and update another add-in.

The tricky part is "upon Excel starts". I'm able to check for updates upon opening Excel through the Workbook_Open() event of the helper add-in.
In fact it does work and the other plugin gets updated.

The problem is when the user open Excel clicking on an .xlsx/.xls/.csv/etc file.

I want to detect this and in the case Excel is opened through the Excel icon run the updates check otherwise it has to do nothing.

How can I determine in which way Excel was opened?

**What I tried so far:**

- verifying if there are non-addin Workbooks opened (not working)
- verifying Application.Ready (not working)

both tests are not working because, I think, the helper add-in Workbook_Open event is fired before the empty Workbook is created (in case Excel was launched through its icon) or loaded (in case Excel was launched through the click of an .xls file).

Thank you in advance :)

---

**Possible solution implemented, checking command line parameters:**
https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/247/read-command-line-parameters-from-vba

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetCommandLineA Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Private Declare Function lstrcpynA Lib "kernel32" ( _
   ByVal pDestination As String, ByVal pSource As Long, _
   ByVal iMaxLength As Integer) As Long

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim pCmdLine As Long     ' Pointer to the string
    Dim strCmdLine As String ' Command line string

    ' Get the pointer to the command line string
    pCmdLine = GetCommandLineA

    ' Fill the string with zeros
    ' 300 characters for command line seems to be enough
    strCmdLine = String(300, vbNullChar)

    ' Copy from the pointer to VBA-style string
    lstrcpynA strCmdLine, pCmdLine, Len(strCmdLine)

    ' At this point we got the string
    ' But rest of it filled with 0 characters.
    strCmdLine = Left(strCmdLine, InStr(1, strCmdLine, vbNullChar) - 1)
End Sub
```

If Excel is launched alone the result is:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE"`

otherwise:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" /dde`

Comment: Are you handling `Application.Workbook_Open` events in the helper add-in, or just the `ThisWorkbook.Workbook_Open` event of the add-in?

Comment: Just `ThisWorkbook.Workbook_Open`, do you think I've a chance with `Application.Workbook_Open`? I'm not able to think it out.

Comment: I was thinking that you might be able to test if `Wb.Path <> vbNullString` in `Application.Workbook_Open`.  Haven't tested anything though.

Comment: That could be something, I'll test it (I think it will return the path for the temp xlsx, but I'll test and see)